# How can I access the value of a variable in Dart(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable which was declared initially and which will be changed after a drop down selection. I couldnot access the value after it has been changed by using for loop and c

```
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate = 'Reg No';
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate1 = 'Reg No';
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate2 = 'Reg No';
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate3 = 'Reg No';
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate4 = 'Reg No';
   String _selectedRegNoUpdate5 = 'Reg No';

 for(int i = item!['workedWith'].length; i < 6 ; i++){
                                                                                                      
   print(i.toString());                                                                                                        
   String workedWithPosition = '_selectedRegNoUpdate$i';
                                                                                                      
   print(workedWithPosition);  // this prints _selectedRegNoUpdate3
                                                                                                      
   print(_selectedRegNoUpdate4);   // this prints the value which is stored in _selectedRegNoUpdate4 which is 12345
                                                                                                      
   print(workedWithPosition);  //but this print Reg No3 not the value selected by the drop down selector
                                                                                                      
   print((_selectedRegNoUpdate+i.toString()).toString());
                                                                                                    
 };
```

Comment: Can you include the full code

Comment: The full code is long and would be hard to copy here. Which part of the code do you want me to share, the hole is like 1260 lines

Comment: Variable names ending in digits is a code smell.  Those values should have been in a data structure of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, in Dart, point to a variable directly based on a `String` value (unless we use reflection with `dart:mirrors` which are not supported on lot of platforms).

What you should do instead is create a `List<String>` which contains your values. This list can you then search using an `index` number.

```dart
List<String> _selectedRegNoUpdate = [
  'Reg No 1',
  'Reg No 2',
  'Reg No 3',
  'Reg No 4',
  'Reg No 5',
  'Reg No 6',
];

void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < _selectedRegNoUpdate.length; i++) {
    print(_selectedRegNoUpdate[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above answer. I added the drop down values as they were selected. Thank you